# 1 pixel white line problem with two monitors , 13.04

Tags: unity

I find a problem with fullscreen gnome-terminal

When its lost the focus its get 1 px line at right and top
Also it have 1px white line at right if not in fullscreen

see screenshots please

[image]

[image]

this Ubuntu version 12.10, and also doesn't have this problem on 12.04

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Same problem for me. I have a Samsung SyncMaster B1930N. As I saw monitor needs 1366 resolution (for 18.5") but ubuntu shows only 1300. Maybe is same problem in your case.